Trying to understand length recovery attack on EAP-MD5
I'm failing to understand how length recovery attack works in EAP-MD5 described in this paper on page 6: https://inria.hal.science/hal-01534313/document
I setup wpa_supplicant to be the client side, and I'm pretending to be the authentication service.
In supplicant, I'm using password your_password so I'm trying to find out the length of 13.
In the linked research paper in the step 1, it says to decide a fixed ID and a fixed challenge C, so I chose:
ID: 2
Challenge: test

Step 3 instructs to send the challenge to the client and I get the expected response from supplicant: 2b12c27832f9da6fdb1ad4ae6cce2623 which is MD5(2||your_password||test)
Perhaps my problem is that I do not understand why I need this response in the first place.
Since I know the password length (13), I immediately try to verify this length so I calculate the padding for 2your_passwordtest, which is 0x80 and 37 0x0 bytes.
So then for step 6 I generate a new message C||pad||r ('random' as the string for this):
74 65 73 74 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 72 61 6e 64 6f 6d
Again, I send this to the supplicant, and get the response R': 9e5f3343dc579d2bea7341bd0bbd30bc
I calculated the padding-2 for the second challenge:
80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Now here is the second part I don't fully understand, I think I'm supposed to MD5(random||padding-2), so that would be md5 of 72 61 6e 64 6f 6d 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
But that yields 4af1fbc475c3e8916aa0ac302c758ee2 - which is not same as R'...
Where do I go wrong here ?
